# Dividing matrices with different number of rows and columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, division

I am not entirely sure if what I am trying to do is possible and googling isn't helping me a lot, so I decided to ask here. So, I have two matrices:

```
carrots <- matrix(sample(0:100,5), nrow=1, ncol=5, dimnames = list( c('carrots'), paste0("carrot",1:5)) )
```

and

```
Bunny <- matrix(c(1:16), nrow=2, ncol=8,dimnames = list(c(1:2), c('ck', 'Bunny1', 'Bunny2', 'unit', 'Bunny3', 'Bunny4', 'rating', 'Bunny5')))
```

The output is as follows:

```
           carrot1 carrot2 carrot3 carrot4 carrot5
carrots      86      41     100      53      66

  ck Bunny1 Bunny2 unit Bunny3 Bunny4 rating Bunny5
1  1      3      5    7      9     11     13     15
2  2      4      6    8     10     12     14     16
```

What I want to do is divide each of the Bunny columns (Bunny1-5) by the carrot columns. The problems is, the dimensions of the carrot matrix is different from the Bunny one, so according to math, I can't divide the matrices. Is there a way around that, that does not involve explicitly dividing each Bunny 1 - 5 by carrot 1 -5 ? I tried using sweep() but that didn't help. Maybe a dataframe would come in handy ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Subset the `Bunny` columns based on the column pattern and then divide after replicating the 'carrots'

```
tmp <- Bunny[,startsWith(colnames(Bunny), "Bunny")]
tmp/carrots[col(tmp)]
```

Or use `sweep`

```
sweep(tmp, 2, carrots, `/`)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you solved my problem !